# Visual style anomaly in extended open/save file dialog

Tags: .net, windows, user-interface, savefiledialog

I followed [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8086/Extending-the-save-file-dialog-class-in-NET) that explains how Windows's built-in file open/save dialogs can be extended using .NET. After some minor changes everything works fine but the appearance of the dialog is slightly different from other dialogs. It's not critical, yet I am curious what could be the reason behind it.

My dialog (flat buttons): 
[image: My Dialog (flat buttons)]

Other dialogs (3D buttons): [image: Other dialogs (3D style buttons)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments of that article:

> The SaveFileDialogWithEncoding example is great. However, the look and feel are "old style" -- in other words, the buttons and controls don't have the new "XP look" (i.e. rounded buttons, etc.). It's probably a flag setting in one of the fields in the OPENFILENAME structure and I'm looking into that. I was just wondering if you (or anyone else) had any insight to solving that problem.

and then the self-answer:

> Never mind -- figured it out. Before you instantiate the form object you need to call Application.EnableVisualStyles() like so:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: Oops, I overlooked the comment. Thanks a lot for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

LarsTech's solution seems to work in most cases but seemingly not for Office add-ins. Here implementing `EnableThemingInScope` as described [in this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;830033) and using it with the following code helps.

```
using( new EnableThemingInScope( true ) )
{
    if (!GetSaveFileName(ref ofn))
    {
        int ret=CommDlgExtendedError();

        if (ret!=0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Couldn't show file open dialog - " + ret.ToString());
        }

        return DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```